# Explanation needed on a "find | awk" command (Linux)

Tags: linux, shell, awk

I am trying to figure out the command below;

```
find ./ -type f |
awk -F / -v OFS=/ '{$NF="";dir[$0]++} END {for (i in dir) print dir[i]i}'
```

the output is like:

```
6./Release_1_18_1_0_06_26/metadata/3_Control_Files/   
5./Release_1_18_1_0_06_26/metadata/7_SAS_Code/   
5./Release_1_18_1_0_06_26/others/1_content/   
1./.cache/pip/selfcheck/   
2./Release_1_18_1_0_06_26/metadata/5_Status/   
1./Release_1_18_1_0_06_26/compute/2_packages/   
1./sasuser.v94/   
4./metadata/FR1_Release_1.17.1.1/3_Control_Files/   
4./Release_1_18_1_0_06_26/metadata/6_Patches/
```

This command am counting the number of incode in the current path. However, I did not understand `{$NF="";dir[$0]++} END {for (i in dir) print dir[i]i}`, especially `dir[$0]`. anyone can explain that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you please go through following, detailed explanation of OP's code here.

```
find ./ -type f |     ##Running find command to find files in current directory and passing output as input to awk command.
awk -F / -v OFS=/ '   ##Running awk command setting field separator and output field separator as /
{
  $NF=""              ##Nullifying last field of current line here.
  dir[$0]++           ##creating array dir with current line and keep increasing its value with one here.
}
END{                  ##starting END block of this code here.
  for(i in dir){      ##traversing through dir array here.
    print dir[i]i     ##printing index of dir array and it's index here.
  }
}'
```

***NOTE:***`END` block of any `awk` code is executed when Input_file is being done with reading at last.

Comment: Nice. dir[$0] can remember the last count for its line, That is why the array can increase the value.

Answer (score 3):

The `-F /` tells awk to split the line by slashes.  `$0` is the whole line.

`$NF=""` replaces the last item on the line (in this case the filename) with blank.

Then `dir[$0]++` takes the whole line (after the filename as been removed) and uses that as the index into a hash, incrementing that value by one.  Effectively counting the number of items that had the same path.

The `END` block loops through all keys in the `dir[]` hash printing first the count, then the directory name.